# Public transport from Woodstock, NY to Bangor, ME?

Tags: trains, new-york-state, maine

I'm looking to take train from Woodstock, New York to Portland or Bangor, Maine.

The trip is actually from Woodstock, NY to Fredericton, New Brunswick. We can rent a car for part of the trip from Portland or Bangor, but it would be nice not to drive the whole trip.

Is public transport available from Woodstock to Bangor?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the only west-to-east train is the lake shore limited, which takes 5 hours to get you from Albany to Boston.  Plus you'd have to drive an hour to Albany.  You could also drive down to NYC and take the northeast corridor service, but that will take a similar amount of time, when driving directly to Boston is less than 4 hours, and driving directly to Portland is maybe 5 hours. Taking the train will require all day. It's only worth it if you very much hate driving or love trains.

Comment: You don't have to drive to Albany or NYC; Amtrak's Empire Service between the two cities stops in Rhinecliff, less than 20 miles from Woodstock.

Comment: @NateEldredge true, though Amtrak's planner sends you through NYC so I guess that's faster.  Then you have to wait 1 to 2 hours in Penn Station. Rhinecliff to Boston is 7 to 8 hours. You can then drive or take the train or bus to Portland.  The whole thing takes 10 or 11 hours.  I'd prefer a 5-hour drive to that schlep any day, but that's just me.

Comment: If you've got 36 hours to spare, you can get all the way to Fredericton entirely on public transit.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can go on public transport between Woodstock, NY (or close to it) up to Bangor, ME. You even have multiple options.

## Train

As found in the comments, the closest train station to Woodstock, NY is Rhinecliff, NY. Searching (in two separate times, since [Amtrak](https://www.amtrak.com/)'s search engine does not seem to aggregate itineraries properly when there are too many connections), you can take the Empire Service down to New York (1h40) and then go by train from New York to Portland, ME with the Northeast  Regional and the Downeaster. Portland to Bangor is operated by bus. It's taking pretty much an entire day (11AM to 10.30PM for example).

[image: Amtrak itinerary]

## Bus

[Greyhound](https://www.greyhound.com/) also offers (cheaper) bus trips between Woodstock, NY and Bangor, ME. Once again, you will switch 3 times, including New York and Boston. The trip takes also a day (7AM to 10PM). The convenience is that you actually start from a bus station in Woodstock, NY (you don't have to have someone driving you 20 miles).

## Mixed

[Rome2Rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Woodstock-Event-NY-USA/Bangor-ME-USA) shows you can mix bus and train, still switching (only twice !) in New York and Boston. The trip would also be long, taking you about 12 hours. And once again, the bus station is in Bethel Woods, NY, a 15 min walk from Woodstock (according to Rome2Rio).

So you have multiple options to travel with public transport in the Northeast. If you are interested in following your itinerary to Canada, [there is a question covering the topic](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/16007/getting-from-halifax-canada-to-the-us-by-bus-train).